# RVM - Automatically use a certain Ruby version for a given command?

Tags: rvm

I have some commands that need particular version of Ruby e.g. Chef's knife command seems to work best with 2.0.0 while [sup](https://github.com/sup-heliotrope/sup) works best with 1.9.2. Is there a way, without writing a wrapper script or manually do "rvm use", that when I execute "sup" it will use 1.9.2 and when I execute knife it will use "2.0.0"?

I realise this question is not strictly "development" but there are lots of RVM questions on SO already so I figured it was a good place to ask.

Comment: I'm pretty sure not. How would that work behind the scenes?

Comment: Good question - I thought I would just throw it out there anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rvm generates wrappers for you:

```
rvm wrapper 2.0.0 --no-prefix knife
rvm wrapper 1.9.2 --no-prefix sup
```

assuming you do not install this gems in all rubies the default from `$rvm_path/bin/` will be used with loading proper ruby.